# Csv optional quote with gawk

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

I need to use "FPAT" or the equivalent function "patsplit" of gawk. But it seems the installed version of gawk is 3.1.5 on our CentOs server.

I tried updating gawk with these commands:

```
yum update gawk;
```

And the server showed:  "No Packages marked for Update"

I also tried reinstalling gawk with:

```
 yum install gawk;
```

server output: "Package gawk-3.1.5-15.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
"

Where i need gawk 4.0 or above to use those FPAT OR patsplit. And why i need to use them? well i am trying to process a CSV file, and it seems the CSV file has optional quotation and embedded comma.

Example:

From a csv row like this:

```
this,is,a,"csv,with,embedded coma"
```

I need to split the fields like this:

```
this

is

a

"csv,with,embedded comma"
```

And here is the gawk code:

```
awk '{patsplit("this,is,a,\"csv,with,embedded comma\"",a,"([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\"[^,]*)",seps); for(i=0;i<length(a);i++) print a[i];}';
```

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using csvquote in your pipeline to make the data easy for awk to interpret. This is a script I wrote that replaces the commas inside quoted fields with nonprinting characters, and then restores them.

So if your awk command looked like this originally:

```
awk -F, '{print $3 "," $5}' inputfile.csv
```

... it can be made to work with csv quoted separators like this:

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | awk -F, '{print $3 "," $5}' | csvquote -u
```

For code and more documentation, see https://github.com/dbro/csvquote

Answer (score 1):

I think we could use match() to get the fields.

here are the codes:

```
awk '{ $0=$0","                                   
while($0) {
  match($0,/ *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/) 
  field=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)            
  gsub(/,$/,"",field)   
  print field
  $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1)              
}}' file
```

test with your input example:

```
kent$  echo 'this,is,a,"csv,with,embedded coma"'|awk '{
$0=$0","                                   
while($0) {
  match($0,/ *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/) 
  field=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)            
  gsub(/,$/,"",field)   
  print field
  $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1)              
}}'
this
is
a
"csv,with,embedded coma"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is convert the commas outside of the quotes to something else before you do your real processing. For example:

```
$ cat file
this,is,a,"csv,with,embedded coma",and,here,"is,another",one
and,here,"is,another,line"
$
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,";",$i)}1' file
this;is;a;"csv,with,embedded coma";and;here;"is,another";one
and;here;"is,another,line"
```

If you don't like ";"s as field separators, pick something else like a control character or here's an example using newlines as the FSs and blank lines as the RSs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""; ORS="\n\n"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,"\n",$i)}1' file
this
is
a
"csv,with,embedded coma"
and
here
"is,another"
one

and
here
"is,another,line"

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""; ORS="\n\n"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,"\n",$i)}1' file |
awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR,i,"<" $i ">"}'
1 1 <this>
1 2 <is>
1 3 <a>
1 4 <"csv,with,embedded coma">
1 5 <and>
1 6 <here>
1 7 <"is,another">
1 8 <one>
2 1 <and>
2 2 <here>
2 3 <"is,another,line">
```

It only gets tricky if you have embedded newlines or embedded escaped double quotes.

Comment: Ooh, **+1** for substituting in every second field separated by quotes!  I'll keep that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure GAWK solution:

```
{ # Split on double quotes to handle lines like "this, this, or this".
    printf("LINE:    '%s'\nFIELDS:", $0)
    n = split($0,q,/"/)
    f = 0
}

n == 1 { # If n is 1, there are no double quotes on the line.
    n = split($0,c,/,/)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("  %d='%s'", i, c[i])
    }
    printf("\n")
    next
}

{ # There are "strings"; the EVEN entries in q are the quoted strings.
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (0 == and(i,1)) { # i is EVEN: This is a double-quoted string.
            printf("  %d='\"%s\"'", ++f, q[i])
            continue
        }
        if (0 == length(q[i])) { # First/last field is a quoted string.
            continue
        }
        if (q[i] == ",") {
            # First/last field empty, or comma between two quoted strings.
            if (i == 1 || i == n) { # First/last field empty
                printf("  %d=''", ++f)
            }
            continue
        }
        # Remove commas before/after a quoted string then split on commas.
        sub(/^,/,"",q[i])
        sub(/,$/,"",q[i])
        m = split(q[i],cq,/,/)
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            printf("  %d='%s'", ++f, cq[j])
        }
    }
    printf("\n")
}
```

With this input:

```
This is one,23,$9.32,Another string.
Line 2,234,$88.34,Blah blah
"This is another",763,$0.00,"trouble, or not?"
"This is, perhaps, trouble too...",763,$0.00,"trouble, or not?"
2,"This is, perhaps, trouble too...",763,"trouble, or not?"
3,,"number, number","well?"
,,,
"1,one","2,two","3,three","4,four"
",commas,","no commas",",,,,,",
,"Fields 1 and 4 are empty","But 2 and 3 are not",
```

This output is produced:

```
LINE:    'This is one,23,$9.32,Another string.'
FIELDS:  1='This is one'  2='23'  3='$9.32'  4='Another string.'
LINE:    'Line 2,234,$88.34,Blah blah'
FIELDS:  1='Line 2'  2='234'  3='$88.34'  4='Blah blah'
LINE:    '"This is another",763,$0.00,"trouble, or not?"'
FIELDS:  1='"This is another"'  2='763'  3='$0.00'  4='"trouble, or not?"'
LINE:    '"This is, perhaps, trouble too...",763,$0.00,"trouble, or not?"'
FIELDS:  1='"This is, perhaps, trouble too..."'  2='763'  3='$0.00'  4='"trouble, or not?"'
LINE:    '2,"This is, perhaps, trouble too...",763,"trouble, or not?"'
FIELDS:  1='2'  2='"This is, perhaps, trouble too..."'  3='763'  4='"trouble, or not?"'
LINE:    '3,,"number, number","well?"'
FIELDS:  1='3'  2=''  3='"number, number"'  4='"well?"'
LINE:    ',,,'
FIELDS:  1=''  2=''  3=''  4=''
LINE:    '"1,one","2,two","3,three","4,four"'
FIELDS:  1='"1,one"'  2='"2,two"'  3='"3,three"'  4='"4,four"'
LINE:    '",commas,","no commas",",,,,,",'
FIELDS:  1='",commas,"'  2='"no commas"'  3='",,,,,"'  4=''
LINE:    ',"Fields 1 and 4 are empty","But 2 and 3 are not",'
FIELDS:  1=''  2='"Fields 1 and 4 are empty"'  3='"But 2 and 3 are not"'  4=''
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to yum, which should be called dnf now, see

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software)

then you could just run **as a normal user**

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/gawk.git
cd gawk
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then your question of a tmp.txt input file of

```
this,is,a,"csv,with,embedded coma"
```

is easily converted by

```
gawk '{patsplit("this,is,a,\"csv,with,embedded comma\"",a,"([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\"[^,]*)",seps); for(i=0;i<length(a);i++) print a[i];}' tmp.txt
```

you may have issue compiling gawk, you should address those if they pop up.